# Calculate column based on other column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The result of `sql` select statement looks as below:

```
select * from table

Location    Role              Days
-----------------------------------
Hong Kong   Senior Associate  48
Canberra    Senior Associate  60
Sydney      Senior Associate  55
```

I want to add a column to above result - `Hours` (there is no hours column in the SQL Server table).

`Hours` should be calculcated based on location

- If Hong Kong then Days/7
- If Canberra then Days/7.5
- If Sydney then Days/7.25

The result should be like:

```
Location    Role              Days Hours
-----------------------------------------
Hong Kong   Senior Associate  48   6.85
Canberra    Senior Associate  60   8
Sydney      Senior Associate  55   7.586
```

I tried with `select case` which will check only one condition (if and else) and column should be in database.

```
select 
    case 
       when location = 'Sydney' 
          then Days/7 
       else Days/7.5 
    end as Hours
```

But I want all to be conditions to be checked in one SQL statement and add hours column which is not in database.

Any advice please.

Comment: You should show your query with the `case`.

Comment: sure,  i will show that

Comment: select case when location = 'Sydney'
            then Days/7 
            else Days/7.5      
  end as Hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `case` solves this:

```
select location, role, days,
       (case when location = 'Hong Kong' then days / 7.0
             when location = 'Canberra' then days / 7.5
             when location = 'Sydney' then days / 7.25
        end) as hours
from t;
```

You can even add this column to the table using a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add hours as (case when location = 'Hong Kong' then days / 7.0
                       when location = 'Canberra' then days / 7.5
                       when location = 'Sydney' then days / 7.25
                  end);
```

Answer (score 1):

In you query:

```
SELECT ...
       (CASE when location = 'Hong Kong' then days / 7.0
             when location = 'Canberra' then days / 7.5
             when location = 'Sydney' then days / 7.25
        end) AS Hours
```

You can use `LOWER()` or `UPPER()` to ignore case-sensitive matching like `LOWER(location) = LOWER('Hong Kong')`

Hope this helps!